# TypeError: addData() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'title', 'years', 'author', and 'isbn' what is the problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bookInfodb = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
        self.c = self.bookInfodb.cursor()
        self.bookInfodb.commit()
        self.c.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (title TEXT, author TEXT, year TEXT, isbn TEXT)")
        self.title("book info")
        self.minsize(500, 320)
        self.configure(background="gray")
        self.datas()

    def addData(self, title, years, author, isbn):

        self.c.execute(
            "INSERT INTO books VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (title, author, year, isbn))
        self.bookInfodb.commit()

    def datas(self):
        self.title = StringVar()

        self.titleEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="titel")
        self.titleEntry.place(x=41, y=10)

        entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.title)
        entry.place(x=66, y=10)

        # make years input

        self.years = IntVar()

        self.yearsEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="years")
        self.yearsEntry.place(x=269, y=10)

        entry2 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.years)
        entry2.place(x=300.5, y=10.2)

        # make author input

        self.author = StringVar()

        self.authorEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="author")
        self.authorEntry.place(x=40, y=51)

        entry3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.author)
        entry3.place(x=80, y=51)

        # make isbn input

        self.isbn = IntVar()

        self.isbnEntry = ttk.Label(self, text="isbn")
        self.isbnEntry.place(x=270, y=52)

        entry_iv = Entry(self, textvariable=self.isbn)
        entry_iv.place(x=297, y=52)

        # buttons

        save_button = Button(self, text=" save ", command=self.addData)
        save_button.place(x=66, y=150)


windows = root()
windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=self.addData` will not just magically pass the correct arguments when it calls `self.addData`. That function could just use `self.title`, `self.years`, etc and not require any arguments in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the command argument from `save_button = Button(self, text=" save ", command=self.addData)` to a `lambda` and pass the expected arguments...

```
save_button = Button(
    self,
    text=" save ",
    command=(
        lambda t=self.title, y=self.years, a=self.author, i=self.isbn: self.addData(t, y, a, i)
    )
)
```

As @Random Davis pointed out, however, you can skip this altogether like so:

```
def addData(self):  # no params needed - access values through 'self'
    self.c.execute(
        "INSERT INTO books VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
        (self.title, self.author, self.year, self.isbn)
    )
    self.bookInfodb.commit()
```